# Bulk variable assignment

Tags: vimrc

Is there anyway to combine variable assignments in vim? For example, say I have:

```
let q1 = ""
let q2 = ""
let q3 = ""
let q4 = ""
```

Is there an alternative, such as:

```
let q1, q2, q3, q4 = "", "", "", ""
```

Or:

```
let q1=q2=q3=q4=""
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `:h :let-unpack`, i.e.

```
let [foo, bar, baz] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Help-topic: `:h :let-unpack`.

Comment: Also, given they should all share the same initial value, `repeat()` can be used. Even if we ignore this will lead to troubles with _reference_ types, (list & dict), in all cases it's really ugly.